# how to make an animated population pyramid for different country

Tags: r

I have a data frame named `mydata`, which contains population for different `country`.

```
df<- data_frame(age= c(0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70), gender = "male", 
population =c(180,160,130,140,150,160,170,90,85,80,75,70,65,60,40), country = 1)
                
df1<- data_frame(age= c(0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70), gender = "female", 
population =c(160,150,120,130,140,150,160,80,75,70,65,60,55,50,30),country  = 1)

df2<- data_frame(age= c(0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70), gender = "male", 
population =c(185,165,135,148,159,166,177,99,89,88,74,73,68,63,43), country = 2)

df3<- data_frame(age= c(0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70), gender = "female",
population =c(200,190,45,77,121,131,190,68,89,98,54,23,68,76,23), country = 2)

df4<- data_frame(age= c(0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70), gender = "male", 
population =c(85,65,35,48,59,66,177,99,89,88,54,33,88,66,23), country = 3)
                 
df5<- data_frame(age= c(0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70), gender = "female",
population =c(149,120,80,70,66,44,57,87,71,32,96,31,29,20,11), country = 3)

mydata<- rbind(df,df1,df2,df3,df4,df5)
```

In the code below, I got a population pyramid for three countries. Now, I want to animate the three pyramids so that I have the changes of the three countries.

```
pop<- ggplot(data=mydata, aes(x=age, y = ifelse(gender == "male", - population, population), fill=gender)) + 
geom_col() + 
facet_wrap(~country) +
coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gganimate` to do this:

```
library(gganimate)

pop <- ggplot(data = mydata, aes(
  x = as.factor(age),
  y = ifelse(gender == "male",-population, population),
  fill = as.factor(gender))) +
  geom_col(aes(group = as.factor(age))) +
  coord_flip() +
  xlab("Population") +
  ylab("Age") +
  transition_states(country, transition_length = 2, state_length = 1) +
  labs(title = 'Country: {closest_state}', fill= "Gender") +
  ease_aes('linear')

# For saving the animation (though you can change the size, resolution, etc.)
anim_pop <- animate(pop)
anim_save(animation = anim_pop, filename ="pop.gif")
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @Andy Brown but it is not my desired output. please see this  link for my desire output https://rpubs.com/walkerke/india_pyramid

Comment: Are you wanting 3 separate plots or wanting 1 plot that changes by country? In the example, they are changing the graph by time? Are you wanting it to change by country?

Comment: @ Andy Brown that is exactly what I want. I want 1 plot that changes by country

Comment: I got this error : `file_renderer failed to copy frames to the destination directory `

Comment: When doing `anim_save`? You'll need to specify a directory for it to save to (e.g., `filename = "/Desktop/pop.gif"`

Comment: No, when doing `pop <- animate(pop)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234082/discussion-between-andy-brown-and-mehmo).